# How to add a new row everytime a user asks to?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

My task is to create a function that adds a row to a 2d Array everytime that a user asks to. For simplicity, I have a default row value to start with and a column value that should be kept. This task can be referenced to a bookshelf. Once a certain amount of books or on that row of the bookshelf, then move to the next row and begin placing books there.

Additionally, how should I free the program once a new row is created?
I am a new programmer and do apologize if my question sounds dumb. Thanks in advance!

Attached is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int **addRows(int row, int cols, int values)
{
    // Declare a 2d Array
    int **twoD;
    twoD = new int *[row];
    // Fill each row with a column
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        twoD[i] = new int[cols];
    }
    // Fill each row, column with value
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            twoD[i][j] = values;
        }
    }

    // Return the 2d array
    return twoD;
}

int main()
{
    int **twoD;
    int row = 1;
    int cols = 5;
    int values = 1;
    int userInput;

    // Call the function with 3 parameters by assigning the returned array to twoD
    twoD = addRows(row, cols, values);
    cout << "Do you want to add a row? 1 for yes, 0 for no, -1 to exit";
    cin >> userInput;

    while (userInput != -1)
    {
        if (userInput == 1)
        {
            twoD = addRows(row, cols, values);
        }
        else
        {
            // Print out each value in the 2d Array to console
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    cout << twoD[i][j];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            // Free the memory
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
            {
                delete (twoD[i]);
            }

            delete (twoD);
        }
        cout << "Do you want to add a row? 1 for yes, 0 for no, -1 to exit";
        cin >> userInput;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Not allowed to use vectors, unfortunately. Limited to only dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: if you are not allowed to use `std::vector` then the solution is to write a `my::vector` and use that. Seriously. RAII is your friend. Make sure to respect the rule of 3/5, then almost nothing can go wrong anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the following lines:

```
    //remove memory allocation of array of columns for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        delete[] twoD[i];
    }
    //remove memory allocation of array of rows
    delete[] twoD;
    //increase the amount of rows in our new twoD matrix
    row++;
```

in this section:

```
    if (userInput == 1)
    {
        //right here
        twoD = addRows(row, cols, values); //call addRows to generate the new twoD matrix with the increased row count
    }
```